# Minecraft GUI plugin, unable to check for enchantments properly in 1.13.2 - Paper #501

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am attempting to make Chest GUI plugin. here is the code I have

```
if (block.getType() == Material.ENCHANTING_TABLE) { //create the GUI
e.setCancelled(true);
//Line 1
if (e.getItem().getType() == Material.AIR) {
    e.setCancelled(true);
    Common.tell(player, "&c&l(!)&c Please hold an item in your hand!");
}

System.out.println(listOfAllowedItems);
System.out.println(e.getItem());
System.out.println(enchant);
if (enchant.isEmpty() && !listOfAllowedItems.contains(enchant.toString()))
{
    Common.tell(player, "&c&l(!)&c This item cannot not be &d&nEnchanted!");
}
if (listOfAllowedItems.contains(enchant.toString()) && !listOfAllowedItems.isEmpty()) {
    final Map<Enchantment, Integer> enchantments = e.getItem().getEnchantments();
    System.out.println(enchantments);
    if (enchantments.keySet() == null || enchantments.isEmpty() == true) {
        inventory.setItem(0, protection1);
        inventory.setItem(1, protection2);
        inventory.setItem(2, protection3);
        player.openInventory(inventory);
    }
    if (e.getItem().containsEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL) && e.getItem().getEnchantmentLevel(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL) == 1); {
        inventory.setItem(1, protection2);
        player.openInventory(inventory);
    }
    if (e.getItem().containsEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL) && e.getItem().getEnchantmentLevel(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL) == 2); {
        inventory.setItem(2, protection3);
        player.openInventory(inventory);
    }
}
else {
    Common.tell(player, "&c&l(!) Error! &cPlease notify a &nmember of staff&c and cite error FSP.EnchGUI.Failure");
}
```

Here, listOfAllowedItems prints an array list of allowed items.
e = player interact event.
enchant = enchantments of the item.

The issue is that litsOfAllowedItems never contains enchant.toString(). and the if statements end up going completely awry.

Here is a console snippet of when I right click and enchantment table with an item.

```
[23:05:49 INFO]: [DIAMOND_SWORD, DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE, DIAMOND_HELMET, DIAMOND_BOOTS, DIAMOND_LEGGINGS]
[23:05:49 INFO]: ItemStack{DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE x 1, UNSPECIFIC_META:{meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, enchants={PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL=1}}}
[23:05:49 INFO]: {Enchantment[minecraft:protection, PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL]=1}
```

I am attempting to check for, If the item is in the list of allowed items (and this isnt empty) then if it has Prot 1 then do this, Prot 2 do that and No enchantments do something else. It also should check for if the item is air/null.

In the above snippet, I clearly used a DiamondChestplate that is enchanted with Prot 1. In another instance if I use a daylight sensor and I right click the block. Both

```
Common.tell(player, "&c&l(!) Error! &cPlease notify a &nmember of staff&c and cite error FSP.EnchGUI.Failure")

and 

 Common.tell(player, "&c&l(!)&c This item cannot not be &d&nEnchanted!")
```

fire.

Comment: Noted and fixed.

Comment: Regarding e.setItem().isEmpty, when I print  `enchantments` (whilst holding nothing or holding something that is not enchanted) I just get {} in console indicating it is empty.

Comment: Then that might be something weird Bukkit does. \*Shrug*